# Importar varias hojas de excel a R con sus nombres y realizar calculos entre ellas

Tags: r, rstudio, r-dplyr

Tengo un excel con el valor agregado por sector con una cantidad de hojas de acuerdo a provincias argentinas. Para importar este excel utilizo el siguiente comando:

```
df_sheets <- lapply(excel_sheets("C:/Users/MiPc/Downloads/jurisdiccion_52sectores.xlsx"),
                    read_excel,
                    path="C:/Users/MiPc/Downloads/jurisdiccion_52sectores.xlsx")
```

El resultado es una serie de listas correspondientes a cada provincia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cómo puedo hacer para que finalmente quede un DataFrame en formato long cuyas columnas sean "provincia", "sector" y "año"?

El archivo es de acceso público, esta cargado en la página de Comisión Económica Para América Latina Y El Caribe (CEPAL) en el siguiente link:

https://www.cepal.org/es/publicaciones/47900-desagregacion-provincial-valor-agregado-bruto-la-argentina-base-2004

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es generar una columna nueva e indicar el nombre de la planilla como `provincia`, por último `bind_rows()` para unir todos los `data.frame` en uno solo. Nota: No lo verifiqué, pero imagino que el rango de datos es el mismo en las 24 provincias más CABA)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(readxl)

xls_file <- "C:/Users/MiPc/Downloads/jurisdiccion_52sectores.xlsx"
sheets <- excel_sheets(xls_file)[-1] # Quitamos la primer hoja

read_exsheets <- lapply(sheets,
                        FUN=function(s) {
                          df <- read_excel(sheet = s,
                                           range = "B6:U58",
                                           path=xls_file)
                          cbind(provincia=s, df)
                        })


df <- bind_rows(read_exsheets)

# Verificamos el resultado final
df %>% 
  filter(`Sector de actividad económica` == 'Pesca') %>% 
  select(provincia, `2004`, `2019`)


              provincia       2004       2019
1  Ciudad_de_Buenos_Aires  37.171342  26.482185
2            Buenos_Aires 458.773339 701.474426
3               Catamarca   0.000000   0.000000
4                 Cordoba   0.000000   0.000000
5              Corrientes   3.428052   8.041781
6                   Chaco   3.428052   8.041781
7                  Chubut 362.679851 667.775903
8              Entre_Rios  10.284156  24.125344
9                 Formosa   3.428052   8.041781
10                  Jujuy   0.000000   0.000000
11               La_Pampa   0.000000   0.000000
12               La_Rioja   0.000000   0.000000
13                Mendoza   0.000000   0.000000
14               Misiones   0.000000   0.000000
15                Neuquen  23.732667  55.673870
16              Rio_Negro  44.861804  74.406969
17                  Salta   0.000000   0.000000
18               San_Juan   0.000000   0.000000
19               San_Luis   0.000000   0.000000
20             Santa_Cruz 285.363465 675.370494
21               Santa_Fe  10.284156  24.125344
22    Santiago_del_Estero   0.000000   0.000000
23                Tucuman   0.000000   0.000000
24       Tierra_del_Fuego 199.060667 149.156430
25         No_distribuido   0.000000   0.000000
```